# Display Video in a Augmented image

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality app in Android using `ARCore` library.

I would like to play a video in Augmented image.

I can able to successfully identify an object using `ARCore` Android

But I am not able to play a video exactly on the augmented image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to runt this demo and explore it. it working fine as you want best of luck.  Hope you read arcore document and limitations.  https://github.com/yudiz-solutions/arcore_chromakey_video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here are 5 features you have to check to make sure your app's algorithm is OK**:

1. You have a Supported file format of Video Asset (`mp4` is robust choice).
2. You have an `ArAnchor` which your Video Object is attached to.
3. You have a geometry which your `mp4` Video texture is assigned to.
4. You are rendering your Video Object.
5. The logic of video player is true.

Look at Clayton Wilkinson's brilliant answer in [Need to play Video in ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657403/need-to-play-video-in-arcore) SO post.